# How to detect when a textarea value is changed by a script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, textarea, listener

I would like to check a `textarea` when the value inside it is changed by program.

The code is quite complex so I would rather use an event listener instead of looking for the exact line of code.

Here is how I check:

```
$(".edit.btn.btn-default").on("click", function(){
  alert($("#attribute_fabric_en").val());
  $("#attribute_fabric_en").on("input propertychange",function(){
    alert("test");
  });
});
```

The result: `alert($("#attribute_fabric_en").val());` prints an empty string, but the `textarea` later on will be assigned a value by script; but the listener is not triggered.

At least Chrome tested is not work to capture the event

Comment: Can you please show the HTML in question? Hard to tell what's being captured (or attempted) otherwise.

Comment: You need to press a "edit button" to listen the event? Or anytime?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There is an event for that, in jQuery you can use `$('.textareaId').on('change', console.log($('#textareaId').html())`, It is that simple !
EDIT:
Maybe you don't want to use jQuery, click event is for textarea, contentediatble divs, etc and input event is for form elements such as 
`textArea.addEventListener('change', function(e){ ... }, false);`\n
`inputElement.addEventListener('input', function(e) { ... }, false);`

Comment: this only triggers when user makes the change